# Show who with current date as first line without script

Tags: date, who

I like to get an output on the screen of the who command, buth with the current date on the first line (without the use of a script)

Following does the job, buth I prefer one command.

```
$ who > who
$ date > date
$ cat date who
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this combination:

```
date; who
```

You can also use `&&` to combine commands. However, anything before the `&&` will need to return no error code before the command after `&&` can run.

```
date && who
```

In the latter example, `date` failed for some reason, `who` would never run.